# MonoTouch 5.4 and new iPhone 5 + new XCode

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, iphone-5

Can we install the new XCode supporting iPhone 5 and have it work with MonoTouch 5.4 to create apps that will work on the new screensize?

Comment: Xcode 4.5 is still under NDA (for a few days). In the mean time please contact support@xamarin.com if you have specific questions about it.

Comment: Xamarin needs to create private discussion forum where Apple developer status is confirmed to provide place to discuss Betas and such. It is wasteful of everyone's time not to be able to see common questions, issues, solution, and status regarding MT/MD support of iOS Betas and new devices.

Comment: I think it's called IRC.

Comment: I have tried IRC multiple times in the past without a response. It also does not lend itself to others coming along later to search for similar question. I've been **very happy** with MT support actually. But have been frustrated at lack of forum or mailing list to discuss iOS Betas. Maybe use Apple Beta forums and folks tag subject [MonoTouch]. But would prefer that Xamarin take the lead in pointing customers to preferred Beta discussion platform (support page links to place to discuss Betas). Something maybe for iOS7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redth# has posted a [nice writeup](http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/) on getting your MonoTouch app ready for iPhone5. The key change to your project is to add a new splash image for the new display size, Default-568h@2x.png. I'm sure Xamarin will release a new release that adds a GUI to set this, but you can manually do it now following Redth#'s instructions.

Comment: I've updated the post to include some more code shared from @martinbowling :) http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/